# React.JS - multiple elements sharing a state ( How do I modify only one of the elements without affecting the others? )

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, react-router, reactjs

```
    class App extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { Card: Card }
      }
      HandleEvent = (props) => {
        this.SetState({Card: Card.Active}
         }
      render() {
       return (
         <Card Card = { this.state.Card } HandleEvent={ 
       this.handleEvent }/>
         <Card Card = { this.state.Card } HandleEvent={
       this.handleEvent }/>
       )
      }
    }
     const Card = props => {
        return (
        <div style={props.state.Card} onClick={ 
            props.HandleEvent}>Example</div>
         )
       }
```

Every time I click on one of the cards all of my elements change states, how do I program this to only change card that I clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      0: false,
      1: false
    };
  }

  handleEvent(idx) {
    const val = !this.state[idx];
    this.setState({[idx]: val});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card state={this.state[0]} handleEvent={()=>this.handleEvent(0) } />
        <Card state={this.state[1]} handleEvent={()=>this.handleEvent(1) } />
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}

const Card = (props) => {
  return (<div onClick={() => props.handleEvent()}>state: {props.state.toString()}</div>);
}
```

You can also see it in action [**here**](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KjrolgJdqe42Jv_19s6)

Obviously this is a contrived example, based on your code, in real world application you wouldn't store hardcoded state like `{1: true, 2: false}`, but it shows the concept

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear from the example what is the Card in the constructor. But here the example of how you can modify clicked element.

Basically you can keep only index of clicked element in parent's state, and then pass it as some property to child component, i.e. `isActive` here:

```
const cards = [...arrayOfCards];

class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {

   super(props);
   this.state = { activeCardIndex: undefined }
  }
  HandleEvent = (index) => {
    this.SetState({
      activeCardIndex: index
    });
  }
  render() {
   return ({
      // cards must be iterable
      cards.map((card, index) => {
        return (
          <Card
            key={index}
            Card={Card}
            isActive={i === this.state.activeCardIndex}
            HandleEvent={this.HandleEvent.bind(this, index)}
          />
        ); 
      })
   });
  }
}

const Card = props => {
  // style active card
  const style = Object.assign({}, props.Card, {
    backgroundColor: props.isActive ? 'orange' : 'white',
  });

  return (
  <div style={style} onClick={ 
      props.HandleEvent}>Example</div>
   )
 }
```