# React, make state apply to single element in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 circles that should change src of image when toggled, currently all circles toggle the src when one is clicked. I could use some help with how to get that problem fixed.

This is what i got right now

```js
this.state = {
      fillCircle: false
    };

  circleHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ fillCircle: !this.state.fillCircle });
  };
 
 render() {
    let circles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      circles.push(
        <img
          key={i}
          className="circle"
          onClick={this.circleHandler.bind()}
          src={this.state.fillCircle ? filled_circle : circle}
          alt=""
        />
      );
    }
    return (
        <div>
         {circles}
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Right now you have a single variable to store the state of three circles. You need three variables, one for each circle. Use an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.JS - multiple elements sharing a state ( How do I modify only one of the elements without affecting the others? )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917249/react-js-multiple-elements-sharing-a-state-how-do-i-modify-only-one-of-the-e)

Answer (score 0):

This is because each of those elements needs it's own state. Write a separate component for each circle. Then you would do

```
circles.push(<CircleComponent key={index} />)
```

Inside CircleComponent you would have your state for each Component and toggle for each one of them.
Don't forget about keys as well.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try it, but you should get the concept.

```
this.state = {
    fillCircle: [false,false,false]
};

  circleHandler = (i) => {
        this.setState((prev) => {
            if(prev.fillCircle[i] == false)prev.fillCircle = [false,false,false] // <--
            prev.fillCircle[i] = !prev.fillCircle[i];
            return prev.fillCircle;
        });
  };

 render() {
    let circles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      circles.push(
        <img
          key={i}
          className="circle"
          onClick={()=> this.circleHandler(i) }
          src={this.state.fillCircle[i] ? filled_circle : circle}
          alt=""
        />
      );
    }
    return (
        <div>
         {circles}
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work well, only issue im facing now is that when im clicking a second circle the first one is still up and i need some way to toggle of the one before or mabye clear entire state? What would be best way?

Answer (score 0):

@Dille  Please try below code this should solve your problem.

```
this.state = {
          activeCircle: null
        };

      circleHandler = (i) => {
        this.setState({ activeCircle: i});
      };

     render() {
        let circles = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          circles.push(
            <img
              key={i}
              className="circle"
              onClick={this.circleHandler.bind(this, i)}
              src={this.state.activeCircle === i ? filled_circle : circle}
              alt=""
            />
          );
        }
        return (
            <div>
             {circles}
            </div>
        );
```